# Can't use this.NavigationService

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

In the documentation of [NavigationService.Navigate Method (Uri)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms591053%28v=VS.110,d=hv.2%29.aspx) is this code snippet:

```
void goButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(this.addressTextBox.Text));
}
```

But `this.NavigationService` is not available in my `Window` class where I want to call it. Basically I want to switch pages using the *MVVM-Light Toolkit* and all the tutorials use that method, but I can't. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [`NavigationWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationwindow.aspx) to use the `NavigationService`